# How to draw polyline along with multi marker in google map

Tags: google-maps, marker, polyline

I need to draw polyline for the more than one vehicle that are being tracked in our Appln in PHP and google map. Could any one plz tell me how to draw poly line for multiple vehicle with latitude and longitude got from Mysql Database.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to fish out your lat and lon values per vehicle out of the database, and then use the API to create markers, as explained [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers)